# angularJs routing unknown issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello i am new to angularJs and i have some unknown problem
app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular
.module('App', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngAria',
'ngCookies',
'ngMessages',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

main.js

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.num = 7;

    $rootScope.left_side = 2;
    $rootScope.right_side = 2;
});
```

main.html the partial view

```
<p>{{num}}</p>
```

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blog</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body ng-app="App">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-{{left_side}}" ng-if="left_side">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-md-{{12 - left_side - right_side}}">
          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-{{right_side}}" ng-if="right_side">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

so when i go to '/' the scope.num inside ng-view should be rendered but i am not getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main.js you are redeclaring your module's dependencies.
Try Changing:

```
angular.module('App', []).controller
```

to

```
angular.module('App').controller
```